# How should I understand below codes in Django?

Tags: django

**1. define a class in the models.py which was created in my own app.**

```
class Article(models.Model):
    headline = models.CharField(null=True,blank=True,max_length=200)
    content = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.headline
```

**2. define a function in views.py**

```
from firstapp.models import People,Article
def index(request):
    article_list = Article.objects.all()
    context = {}
    context['article_list'] = article_list
    index_page = render(request, 'first_web_2.html', context)
    return index_page
```

The question is: Is the article_list a list?how should I understand "context['article_list'] = article_list"?

Answer (score 2):

Variable article_list is a **queryset**, which is a collection of objects from your database stemming from the query Article.objects.all(). This particular query is much like SELECT * FROM Article.

The **context** is a dictionary where string 'article_list' is the key and the variable article_list is the value. The context is passed to your **template** via the render method where the key is used in your template to render the associated value.

Since you are passing a collection you would have to perform a loop on it in your template. For example, this would render an unordered list of headlines. Note the use of the dot operator to access headline.

```
<ul>
{% for a in article_list %}
      <li> {{ a.headline}} </li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

`article_list` is not a list, it's a [`QuerySet`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/). `QuerySets` are representations of SQL queries via Django's Object Relational Mapper (ORM). It's easy to see them as lists but they are quite different. In any case, you should read Django's documentation about them.

As for `context`, you can think of it as passing variables that you can access in your templates. It could be strings, numbers, lists, QuerySets, dictionaries etc. In this case, you want to be able to access your all your `Articles` in the template, likely so that you can loop through them like `{% for article in article_list %}`. This allows you to then call the attributes like `article.headline` and `article.content` in your template.

Comment: got it, thanks a lot. By the way, if I'd like to query Django's documents to confirm this kind of problem, how should I start? Because I tried to query `models`, as well as `object`, but I almost get nothing if I search with the key words "objects.all" in Django's documents.

Comment: You can just use google and search for django models. But I would recommend that you go through the tutorial, it would be a really good start for you :)

Answer (score 1):

QuerySet's in Django are [iterable](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet) so article_list is not directly a list.

```
context['article_list'] = article_list
```

context is an dict and the entry 'article_list' is sign to the query result article_list.

In the template you can get access to the query set like

```
{% for article in article_list %}
      {{ article }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I believe you can just do `{% for article in article_list %}`

Comment: Thanks man, previously I never heard about QuerySet, I just thought it as a list so it confused me a lot. Sorry I'm new in python and Django.

Comment: You can start with the Django Tutorial https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/intro/tutorial01/ we all struggle at the beginning ;)

Answer (score 0):

You question is hard to understand but I think I got the right answer. You need to read the framework documentation to understand "what that mean":

- context: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/templates/api/#django.template.Context
- queryset (the list) : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#when-querysets-are-evaluated